# mysql fetch data in where condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 table now:

First is : `member_username`

```
+-------------+------------------+
| uid         | username         |
+-------------+------------------+
| 1           | theone           |
| 2           | ohno             |
| 3           | prayforpr        |
+-------------+------------------+
```

Second is : `member_data`

```
+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| uid         | talk              | etc             |
+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| 1           | talk1             |                 |
| 2           | talkeee           |                 |
| 3           | iojdfnl           |                 |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Third is : `member_level`

```
+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| uid         | level             | fid             |
+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| 1           | 2                 | 1               |
| 1           | 10                | 2               |
| 2           | 1                 | 1               |
| 2           | 99                | 2               |
| 1           | 40                | 3               |
| 3           | 50                | 1               |
| 1           | 44                | 4               |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to query data and display the only one uid when `member_level` is higher in when SUM `member_level.level` Where fid in 1,2,3.

my query now is like below, but this query is sum all the level including fid 4 also, how to specify only sum in fid 1,2,3? and how do I assign the SUM of `member_level.level` Where fid in 1,2,3 to $levelKingTotalLevel?

```
$levelKing = DB::query("SELECT t1.uid,t1.username,t2.talk FROM ".DB::table('member_level')." t3 JOIN ".DB::table('member_username')." t1 ON(t3.uid = t1.uid) JOIN ".DB::table('member_data')." t2 ON (t1.uid = t2.uid) GROUP BY t3.uid ORDER BY SUM(t3.level) DESC LIMIT 1");

while($rowlevelKing = DB::fetch($levelKing)) {
    $levelKingTotalLevel = $rowlevelKing['???'];
    $levelKingN = $rowlevelKing['username'];
    $levelKingUID = $rowlevelKing['uid'];
    $levelKingT = $rowlevelKing['talk'];
};
echo "The ".$levelKingN." total level is ".$levelKingTotalLevel." and he talk about ".$levelKingT;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide us samples of both the desired query result and the result you're actually receiving?

Comment: And maybe not write out the whole query on one line like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter records having `fid` values as `1, 2 or 3`, use `IN` statement in `WHERE` clause. Alias `totalLevel` in select statement will give you total level for a user.

```
SELECT t1.uid, t1.username, t2.talk, SUM(t3.level) AS totalLevel
FROM member_level t3
JOIN member_username t1
ON (t3.uid = t1.uid)
JOIN member_data t2
ON (t1.uid = t2.uid)
WHERE t3.fid IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY t3.uid
ORDER BY totalLevel DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: No wonder, previously I try like this `$levelKing = DB::query("SELECT t1.uid,t1.username,t2.talk FROM ".DB::table('member_level')." t3 JOIN ".DB::table('member_username')." t1 ON(t3.uid = t1.uid) JOIN ".DB::table('member_data')." t2 ON (t1.uid = t2.uid) GROUP BY t3.uid ORDER BY SUM(t3.level WHERE t3.fid IN (1,2,3)) DESC LIMIT 1");` , anyway, thank you Samir, your solution solve my problem.